# SQL return specific value there starts with S and has a smaller rownumber

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

i will try to explain.

so i have this table

TABLE

[image: id desc S001001001 Monitors M002002002 24" 1080P M003003003 32" 1080P S002002002 TV M002003003 42" 4K M005005005 48" 8K]

and i want to return this

[image]

is this possible?

i basically want that if the id doesn't start with 'S' the type column value on that line is the first id that starts with S that appears that has a smaller row number then the line in question.

edit:sorry yes it has a column name seq that is the ordering factor

Comment: SQL Tables represent *unordered* sets.  Your question assumes an ordering of the rows, but no column contains that information.  Also, tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

As a starter: for this to be possible, you need a column that defines the ordering of the records - I assumed `ordering_id`.

Then, you can use window functions.

Few databases support the `ignore nulls` option to window functions, that would let you do something like:

```
select t.*,
    case when id not like 'S%' 
        then first_value(case when id like 'S%' then descr end) ignore nuls 
        over(order by ordering_id desc) 
    end type
from mytable
```

Otherwise, we can resort some gaps-and-island technique to build groups of records: the count of preceding "S" records define the groups:

```
select id, descr, 
    case when id not like 'S%' 
        then fist_value(descr) over(partition by grp order by ordering_id) 
    and as type
from (
    select t.*, sum(case when id like 'S%' then 1 else 0 end) over(order by ordering_id) grp
    from mytable t
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an column that specifies the ordering, then you can use the standard function `lag(ignore nulls)`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when id not like 'S%'
             then lag(case when id like 'S%' then desc end ignore nulls) over (order by <ordering col>
        end) as type
from t;
```

I should note that not all databases support the `ignore nulls` option, even though it is part of the standard.

EDIT:

In SQL Server, you can do this in one of two ways.  One method uses a subquery to assign a "group" and then spreading the value over the group:

```
select t.*,
       (case when id not like 'S%'
             then max(desc) over (partition by grp order by ?) 
        end) as type
from (select t.*,
             max(case when id like 'S%' then id end) over (order by ?) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

An alternative is `outer apply`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when t.desc not like 'S%' then t2.desc end) as type
from t outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.*
      from t t2
      where t2.desc like 'S%' and t.id <= t.id
      order by t2.id desc
     ) t2
```

Comment: i tried that and has you said ignore nulls doesnt work, and if i remove that it almost works but only the first id after the S gets the desc correct